# unable twitter login and tweet using twitter4j

Tags: android, android-intent

In twitter integartion i have getting below error:

oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

Comment: need more info. all I can say at this point is "you're doing something wrong".